# How to add messages and tasks to a splash screen progress in an Eclipse RCP application

Tags: progress-bar, eclipse-rcp, splash-screen

I have an Eclipse RCP application which does some time consuming things in the start method of the activator. Now I want to show user friendly messages for these things with progress indication in the splash screen but I do not find any solution for this.

I managed it to have a progressbar with messages in the splash screen but the only thing it shows is "Load Workbench" and this after all the time consuming things are done.

So my question is: how can I add tasks with user friendly messages to the splash screen progress?

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to extend [`org.eclipse.ui.splashHandlers` extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_splashHandlers.html).